# Slow response to query thousands of Route 53 records

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3

I have a requirement to query Route 53 record sets that contain thousands of records.

I need a way to filter out records beginning with a string like "ip-" at the source so that the records can be downloaded in a reasonable time.

At the moment I am using the `aws` command line combined with a JMESPath query:

```
$ date ; aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $hosted_zone_id --query 'ResourceRecordSets[?starts_with(Name, `ip-`)==`false`].Name' | head -4 ; date
Thu May 11 19:16:53 AEST 2017
[
    "foo-pilot.example.com.",
    "foo-pilot.example.com.",
    "bar-dev.foo-pilot.example.com.",
Thu May 11 19:17:04 AEST 2017
```

As can be seen, that is taking 11 seconds and in the application several of these queries are needed, and the result is an unacceptably slow execution time.

The `aws route53 list-resource-record-sets` command ([docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/list-resource-record-sets.html), see also [API doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_ListHostedZones.html)) unfortunately does not accept a `--filter` as some other commands do.

Is there any way to get a filtered subset of the Route 53 records quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to get a filtered subset of the Route 53 records quickly?

Maintain a cache... or create a separate authoritative system that handles all transactions with Route 53 and query that system instead.

The [ListResourceRecordSets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_ListResourceRecordSets.html) API seems only intended for scanning, not querying, so you have to paginate through the results to find what you want.

In fact, it appears that the Route 53 APIs are not intended for high-volume use, since there's also a per-AWS-account limit of [5 req/s](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/DNSLimitations.html#limits-api-requests) for the Route 53 API overall.